# How to render this with CSS grid?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

Hello can somebody help and tell me how to render this with css grid ? 
Actually i made this with jQuery but i know i can probably do this with css grid. 
I want each second element of each row to be offset.

Thank you

[image: My Css Grid Problem]

Comment: You can achieve this by giving a positive `margin-top` alongside an equal-length but negative `margin-bottom`.

Comment: This question does not show research effort. If you are having problems please post your current best guess. You should review [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: This is certainly possible with CSS-Grid but it wouldn't be dynamic I suspect.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You could use .col:nth-child(2) to select the second column if your columns separated in a row div every 3 columns.

Or you can use .nth-child(3n+2) if all your columns are in a same row div.

Some more info from w3schools

> Using a formula (an + b). Description: a represents a cycle size, n is a counter (starts at 0), and b is an offset value.

Comment: The columns are not selectable (or even exist) with CSS-Grid

Comment: Thank you for the help ! https://codepen.io/DevillersJerome/pen/ZoErOe